# Bat file to copy to device based on device name not drive letter

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

Not sure the best way to accomplish this and looking for a point in the right direction.

Currently use a Bat file to fetch Backup files and copy them to an external device.
For example:

```
XCOPY C:\MainFolder\Backups\*.* G:\Backupfolder\ /D /S /E /Y
```

I am trying to encourage users to backup to more than one device and to keep one device offsite. 
The backup usually occurs overnight and is setup as a scheduled task. 
Most of the users are computer illiterate.

As we know, you can plug in multiple USB devices and it will assign it a new drive letter. 
Is there any way i can Copy to a device based on its name opposed to drive letter? 
Its too complicated for users to go into Computer management and assign it the correct drive letter.

The only thing i can think of, is using Bat file to copy to a array of Drive letters, but with this i can see it backing up to things that it should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the Volume name of the removable disk:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" get Name^, VolumeName ^| findstr /i "Name Of USB volume here"') do echo %%i
```

The above will `echo` the drive letter of the volume name.

Where the below will echo both Volumename and Drive letter:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" get Name^, VolumeName ^| findstr /i "Name Of USB volume here"') do echo %%i %%j
```

You can run wmic on its own to see other results:

```
wmic logicaldisk get Name, VolumeName, Caption, DriveType
```

As a side note. Removable drive types are `2`

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't know it was possible using wmic. Nice clean method. Just a FYI if anyone else looks at this in the future. If you want to include more Drivetypes such as logical / removable / network. Then to just use OR i.e. "drivetype=2 or drivetype=3 or drivetype=4"

Comment: @DaveHamilton, well technically, as stated in my answer, limiting it to a drivetype of 2 is not satisfactory to cover all USB drives. Hence the reason that neither of my examples do so. Therefore, if you don't want to limit the results to most USB drives, you should use my more robust answers.

Comment: Sorry i am lost. Both of your examples show drivetype=2. I am just utilising Type 2 and 3, an with Drive type 4 conditionally

Comment: I think you are mistaking compo's comment with me :)

Comment: Anyway, you can simply remove `where "drivetype=2"` entirely from my answer as we use findstr to get the volumename for you, so you will  end up with `for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get Name^, VolumeName ^| findstr /i "Name Of USB volume here"') do echo %%i %%j`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, and possibly because [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) can be a little slow, you could try this from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Drv="
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In (
    'MountVol^|Find ":\"'
)Do Vol %%~dA 2>NUL|Find /I "YourLabel">NUL&&Set "Drv=%%~dA"
If Not Defined Drv Exit /B
Echo Your Drive Letter is %Drv%
Timeout 3 >NUL
```

Just change `YourLabel`, *(on the fifth line above)*, to that you have set as your unique device label.

---

If you wanted to use [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic), because all USB devices are not seen as drive type `2`, it may be safer not to rely on its `DriveType` value. I would therefore suggest this alternative:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Drv="
For /F Skip^=1 %%A In (
    'WMIC LogicalDisk Where "VolumeName='YourLabel'" Get DeviceID 2^>NUL'
)Do For /F Tokens^=* %%B In ("%%A")Do Set "Drv=%%B"
If Not Defined Drv Exit /B
Echo Your Drive Letter is %Drv%
Timeout 3 >NUL
```

Once again changing `YourLabel` as necessary.

---

In both cases you'd obviously change the penultimate line to:

```bat
XCopy "C:\MainFolder\Backups" "%Drv%\Backupfolder\" /D /S /Y
```